# is it clear, grammatical and idiomatic to use "xxx is the only place where xxx"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56514491/10731613) is discussing a jupyter problem.

jupyter is a tool to write program.

I want to express "a functionality works well except for jupyter." by using

> it seems that jupyter cell is the only place where the created file
>   cannot be rendered well.

is this expression clear, grammatical and idiomatic?

Comment: Please let us know what is your specific concern. Otherwise your sentence might be regarded as proofreading.

Comment: The infinitive construction ***to write X*** (where ***X*** is something written) normally takes a plural noun form, as in *He writes books, I write magazine articles.* Hence *This is a tool [with which] to write programs.* Grammatically speaking, it's "valid" to use singular (in which case an article is *required*), but *This is a tool to write **a program*** would rarely be idiomatic.